# Modifying text inside html nodes - nokogiri

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

Let's say i have the following HTML:

```
<ul><li>Bullet 1.</li>
<li>Bullet 2.</li>
<li>Bullet 3.</li>
<li>Bullet 4.</li>
<li>Bullet 5.</li></ul>
```

What I wish to do with it, is replace any periods, question marks or exclamation marks with itself and a trailing asterisk, that is inside an HTML node, then convert back to HTML. So the result would be:

```
<ul><li>Bullet 1.*</li>
<li>Bullet 2.*</li>
<li>Bullet 3.*</li>
<li>Bullet 4.*</li>
<li>Bullet 5.*</li></ul>
```

I've been messing around with this a bit in IRB, but can't quite figure it out. here's the code i have:

```
 html = "<ul><li>Bullet 1.</li>
<li>Bullet 2.</li>
<li>Bullet 3.</li>
<li>Bullet 4.</li>
<li>Bullet 5.</li></ul>"

doc = Nokogiri::HTML::DocumentFragment.parse(html)
doc.search("*").map { |n| n.inner_text.gsub(/(?<=[.!?])(?!\*)/, "#{$1}*") }
```

The array that comes back is parsed out correctly, but I'm just not sure on how to convert it back into HTML. Is there another method i can use to modify the inner_text as such?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

What about this code?

```
doc.traverse do |x|
  if x.text?
    x.content = x.content.gsub(/(?<=[.!?])(?!\*)/, "#{$1}*")
  end
end
```

The `traverse` method does pretty much the same as `search("*").each`. Then you check that the node is a `Nokogiri::XML::Text` and, if so, change the `content` as you wished.

Comment: I do like your code better, as it's a lot cleaner and easier to read. The only problem is if the UL has a text node after it, the period will get replaced there as well. I only want this to happen if it's inside an html node of some sort. (I'm not parsing full HTML docs here). It will probably be only bullet lists and anchor tags that I'll ever run into with this project. I should of clarified my requirements there, cause otherwise your answer is perfect.

Comment: After inspecting the nodes and doing some testing, here's a solution i found that works: http://pastie.org/2450340 Thanks for helping me get here :).

Comment: Then parse as a normal HTML (`Nokogiri::HTML(html)`) and then search like this `doc.search("//li/text()").each do |x|`. Of course, the `if x.text?` is no longer needed.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the post here [Nokogiri replace tag values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2244539/nokogiri-replace-tag-values), I was able to modify it a bit and figure it out.

```
doc = Nokogiri::HTML::DocumentFragment.parse(html)
doc.search("*").each do |node|
  dummy = node.add_previous_sibling(Nokogiri::XML::Node.new("dummy", doc))
  dummy.add_previous_sibling(Nokogiri::XML::Text.new(node.to_s.gsub(/(?<=[.!?])(?!\*)/, "#{$1}*"), doc))
  node.remove
  dummy.remove
end

puts doc.to_html.gsub("&lt;", "<").gsub("&gt;", ">")
```