# Ruby XML Replacing

Tags: ruby, regex, replace

I have an XML file, and I need to replace the text between two tags with a new string
the tags are `<<ConnectionString>ConnectionString>THE OLD TEXT<<ConnectionString>/ConnectionString>`

I need to change this to `<<ConnectionString>ConnectionString>MY NEW TEXT<<ConnectionString>/ConnectionString>`

I can't seem to find anything online, and see that using regex is a bad idea?

Please note, that this file contains more that 1

```
<<ConnectionString>ConnectionString>THE OLD TEXT<<ConnectionString>/ConnectionString>
```

Lines!

Can someone point my in the right direction or an example?
Andrew

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Nokogiri](http://nokogiri.org/) is great for things like this. See the [Nokogiri::Node#content=](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Node.html#method-i-content%3D) method

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri.XML(DATA)             # create a new nokogiri object, this could be a string or IO type (anything which responds to #read)
element = doc.at('ConnectionString') # fetch our element
element.content = "MY NEW TEXT"      # change the content
puts doc #=> <?xml version="1.0"?>\n<ConnectionString>MY NEW TEXT</ConnectionString>


__END__
<ConnectionString>THE OLD TEXT</ConnectionString>
```

Comment: OK, this gets me closing, however (sorry if I'm being dumb) how do I pass my XML document into Nokogiri? Can I just replace DATA with the filename?

Comment: No, replace it with something which responds to the `read` method, or a string. Both `Nokogiri.XML(File.new('foo.xml'))` and `Nokogiri.XML(File.read('foo.xml'))` will work :) (of course it you just passed the filename it would interpret it as an xml string, or fail doing so)

Answer (score 0):

Use [nokogiri](http://nokogiri.org) for dealing with XML files. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2244539/nokogiri-replace-tag-values/2302417#2302417) for the specific task.

Comment: I did see a post about using nokogiri but couldn't see from that post, or sadly your post how I work this into what I want?

Answer (score 0):

I agree in general to use nokogiri over regex in xml but in this case I think it's overkill.

```
xml = open(xmlfile).read.gsub /<ConnectionString>THE OLD TEXT<\/ConnectionString>/, '<ConnectionString>MY NEW TEXT</ConnectionString>'
```

Comment: This looks simpler and easier.. I'll give this a try too